# Remove double slash using Pages

Tags: pages

Link a page usign `{path='site_index'}{page_uri}` (inside an `exp:channel:entries` obviously)
generate this url:

```
http://local.sitename.it:8888//centro-accoglienza/la-struttura
```

How can I remove the double slash after site_index?
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does just the {site_url} variable return?

Comment: It returns `http://local.sitename.it:8888/`

Comment: What's the page URI set to?

Comment: It is `/centro-accoglienza/la-struttura`. I tried to remove the first slash but EE re-insert it.

Comment: Can't you just build the link without the site_index portion? <a href="{page_uri}">View this page</a> ?

Answer (score 1):

Your site URL in your site general configuration (or perhaps your config file, depending on how you set up) likely has a trailing slash which isn't needed. If you remove that it should fix it for you.

In "Admin > General Configuration" this is referred to as "URL to the root directory of your site"

Comment: I tried to do that but the double slash remains...

Comment: When removing the trailing slash where Andrew mentioned does the change 'stick'? In other words when you update that field and you view that settings page again is it gone? If not then your config.php file might not be writeable.